# Java regex: X.Y.Z.A

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match all patterns X.Y.Z.A where X,Y,Z,A are positive integers. For example,

> 10.4.3.9
>
> 11.20.5.6

Right now I have

```
if (str.matches("\d+\\.\d+\\.\d+\\.\d+")) { ... }
```

But for some reason this won't compile. Could anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: Voting to close because the expression is good except for the missing backslashes in front of `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape also the backslash before `d` one more time.

```
if (str.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")) { ... }
```